# How to declare a parameter in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to pass a string parameter "title" and display it in jasper report.

```
var parameters = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
parameters["title"] = "My Title"
val jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource)
```

I have declared parameter in jrxml as this.

```
<jasperReport name="transactions" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
        ...
        <field name="txId" class="java.lang.Long"></field>
        ... 
        <parameter name = "title" class = "java.lang.String"></parameter>
        ...    
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="238" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment = "Center">
            <font size = "22"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$P{title}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        ...
    </jasperReport>
```

But when I run the report generation it does not recognize parameter tag and gives this error.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'parameter'. One of '{field, sortField, variable, filterExpression, group, background, title, pageHeader, columnHeader, detail, columnFooter, pageFooter, lastPageFooter, summary, noData}' is expected.
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:302)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:285)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:274)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:219)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:194)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:288)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
>           at hms.rincewind.merchantportal.service.ReportService.generateReport(ReportService.kt:26)
>           at hms.rincewind.merchantportal.service.TransactionService.getTransactions(TransactionService.kt:32)
>           at hms.rincewind.merchantportal.graphql.api.transaction.TransactionQuery$transactions$1.invokeSuspend(TransactionQuery.kt:23)
>           at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:561)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:727)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:667)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:655)
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'parameter'. One of '{field, sortField, variable, filterExpression, group, background, title, pageHeader, columnHeader, detail, columnFooter, pageFooter, lastPageFooter, summary, noData}' is expected.
>           at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)

Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: `Invalid content was found starting with element 'parameter'`. - Your template is wrong - parameters block should be declared before fields. It is better to use GUI editor (Studio or iReport) for creating/changing template

Comment: @AlexK Yeah. That's the issue. thanks!